# Replace &amp; only in links in a partial html document

Tags: java, parsing

I've tried a few methods (jsoup shown below) to turn `&amp` into `&` only in links.  The difficulty I'm encountering suggests I'm going about this all wrong.  I suspect I'll be facepalming when solutions are offered, but maybe good old regex is the best answer (as I need to only do the replacing in hrefs) unless the reader code is modified?

The parsing libraries (also tried NekoHTML) want to convert all `&`s to `&amp;` so I'm having trouble using them to even get the *true* link hrefs with which to use `String`'s `replace` method.

Input:

```
String toParse = "The <a href=\"http://example.com?key=val&amp;another_key=val.pdf&amp;action=edit&happy=good\">Link with an encoded ampersand (&amp;)</a> is challenging."
```

Desired output:

```
The <a href=\"http://example.com?key=val&another_key=val.pdf&action=edit&happy=good\">Link with an encoded ampersand (&amp;)</a> is challenging.
```

I'm encountering this trying to read an RSS feed that is rendering `<link>`s with `&amp;` instead of `&`.

**Update**
I ended up using regex to identify the links, then using `replace` to insert a decoded link in place of the one with `&amp;`s.  `Pattern.quote()` turned out to be very handy, but I had to manually close and re-open the quoted portions so I could regex or my ampersand condition:

```
final String cleanLink = StringUtils.strip(link).replaceAll(" ", "%20").replaceAll("'", "%27");
String regex = Pattern.quote(link);
// end and re-start literal matching around my or condition
regex = regex.replaceAll("&", "\\\\E(&amp;|&)\\\\Q");
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(result);

while (matcher.find()) {
    int index = result.indexOf(matcher.group());
    while (index != -1) {
        // this replaces the links with &amp; with the same links with &
        // because cleanLink is from the DOM and has been properly decoded
        result.replace(index, index + matcher.group().length(), cleanLink);
        index += cleanLink.length();
        index = result.indexOf(matcher.group(), index);
        linkReplaced = true;
    }
}
```

I'm not thrilled with this approach, but I had to handle too many conditions myself without using a DOM tool to identify links.

Comment: Having an `&amp;` in a URL is actually the standard. Nobody ever writes their URLs like that, but there's nothing wrong with it as a URL, as such.

Comment: Why do you want to replace `&amp;` in `href`s **only**? Why not everywhere? Also, can you show the entire file/document you are dealing with?

Comment: At least for me on my machine, this link fails to properly resolve using Safari, Chrome or Firerox: http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getAllAnswers.do?reference=E-2015-006220&amp;language=EN, but this is ok: http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getAllAnswers.do?reference=E-2015-006220&language=EN.  So for me handling the ampersand properly is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html).  Try `unescapeHtml()` on your `String`.

Comment: Thanks @bphilipnyc!  Using this on `doc.body()` converts `(&amp;)` (not in the href) into `&`.  And `attribute.setValue(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(attribute.getValue()));` also fails to do what I need -- everything in the dom object is still forced into escaped HTML.